# Machine Epsilon meaning

Tags: floating-point, machine-precision

Say we have the floating-point system $(2,3,-1,2)$ and we want to find machine epsilon. According to my textbook, this can be found as $\epsilon_m=\beta^{1-t} = 2^{1-3}=0.25$. However, my textbook also says that $\epsilon_m$ represents the distance between number 1 and the nearest floating-point number such that $1 + \epsilon_m > 1$. Taking the closest numbers to 1 in this system gives me: $$(0.111)\times 2^0 = 0.875; (0.100)\times 2^1= 1 (0.101)\times 2^1 = 1.25$$

Then, since 0.875 is closer to 1 than is 1.25, why is $\epsilon_m$ not 0.125 instead of 0.25?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a matter of definitions. By convention "machine epsilon" means the difference between $1$ and the *next* representable number, not the *previous*.

You quote the definition yourself -- you're looking for an $\epsilon$ such that $1+\epsilon > 1$. Since $0.875$ is *not* greater than $1$, you cannot use that as $1+\epsilon$. So $0.875$ is not the nearest representable number *that is greater than $1$*.

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes sense. So then, $\epsilon_m$ is defined such that whichever number we choose that is closest to 1 _minus_ 1 (no absolute values) is greater than zero right? So that is why we take the next representable number, because $1.25-1 = 0.25 > 0$, while $0.875 - 1 = -0.125 <0$?

Comment: @Bee: Yes indeed.

Comment: @HenningMakholm If you don't mind, could you please take a look at my question here? Thanks! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3410394/question-about-machine-epsilon